# How to find average of two different sql query using php

Tags: php, sql

Below is my code :

```
  $sql = "SELECT count(EventCode) as Total_Event FROM sample where Age between 5 and 10";
  $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql )

  $sql1 = "SELECT count(EventCode) as Total_Event FROM sample where Age between 50 and 80";
  $stmt1 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql1 );
```

From the above query i can able to count the number of events occurs for both `sql` and `sql1` statement .

I need to take average for these 2 queries values `sql` and `sql1`

Please help me how to change my code to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the *average* number of events for people in two different age ranges.  That is really strange, but the easiest way would be a single query:

```
SELECT count(EventCode) / 2 as strange_average_calculation
FROM sample 
WHERE Age between 5 and 10 OR Age between 50 and 80;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a sql function, i.e. `SELECT AVG(column_name)`

```
  $sql = "SELECT AVG(EventCode) as avg_Event FROM sample where Age between 5 and 10";
  $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql )

  $sql1 = "SELECT AVG(EventCode) as avg_Event_2 FROM sample where Age between 50 and 80";
  $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql1 );
```

Comment: k after taking average how i can sum both the values

Comment: if you want to do in sql try this  
function from sql...
SELECT SUM(aggregate_expression)
FROM tables
[WHERE conditions];